# Combine two list objects to form a List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have a list with multiple fields and two objects, My requirements is to form a `List<string>` from objects with '/' separated.

For example : list contains

- object 1:

  - object1[0] = test
  - object1[1] = test2
- object 2:

  - object2[0] = name
  - object2[1] = name 2;

I should get strings in format of test/name, test2/name2;

---

Exact Code :

I am trying inject to model using value injector from List

```
 var resultList = vReturn.ToList();
        List<UserSearchedModel> models = new List<UserSearchedModel>();
        resultList.ForEach(u =>
            {
                UserSearchedModel model = new UserSearchedModel();
                model.InjectFrom(u);
                model.Roles = string.Join(",", ObjectHelper.GetPropertyValue<IList<string>>(u, "Roles", null));
                models.Add(model);
            });

        return models;
```

My list contains two objects i would like to insert in to view model in **Role/GroupCode** Format in seperated.
Role1/GroupCode1, Role2/GroupCode2

Comment: Your `objects` are going to contain same amount of data? in other words, is this true - `object1.Length == object2.Length` ?

Comment: This type of question hints that something is wrong in your domain model.  Consider whether you should define a new class that has the "test, test2" things as one property and the "name, name2" things as a second property.

Comment: Yes they are of same length...

Answer (score 5):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to provide a solution that is sure to fit your needs. But if I understand correctly, you have some way to obtain two separate collections, and you want to merge these collections into a single `List<string>` object.

In this understanding, the fact that these two objects are originally contained in their own list seems irrelevant, so I will ignore that aspect.

Assuming I understand correctly, you probably want to use the `Enumerable.Zip()` method. For example:

```
List<string> Merge(IEnumerable<string> source1, IEnumerable<string> source2)
{
    return source1.Zip(source2, (s1, s2) => s1 + "/" + s2).ToList();
}
```

Use like this:

```
List<string> mergedList = Merge(object1, object2);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ASP.NET or the MVC framework well enough for the code you added to help me elaborate on my answer. If you can explain where in the code you added the `object1` and `object2` lists come from and how you want to use the resulting strings, I can try to elaborate on my answer to explain how it would fit into that particular code example.